# Not able to add platform to ionic

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

I am not able to add platform to ionic its behaving weird

when i run `sudo ionic platform add android`

i get the following error

```
/home/user/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
    at /home/user/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:159:19
    at _fulfilled (/home/user/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/user/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/user/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /home/user/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
    at flush (/home/user/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
Error: /home/user/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

but infact the $ANDROID_HOME has set properly also android command runs on terminal and opens up the SDK manage.

following is my environtment variables

```
:~/myApp$ echo $ANDROID_HOME
/home/user/android-sdks
:~/myApp$ echo $PATH
/home/user/android-sdks/tools/:/home/user/android-sdks/platform-tools/:/usr/local/ant/bin/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin
```

Comment: and have you tried running the `sudo android` command in a shell to check it starts the sdk manager correctly? Or have you tried using directly cordova CLI to add platform? (my understanding is ionic just calls cordova for most commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use sudo for adding platforms, but anyway:

Before adding android Platform try with 
export ANDROID_HOME=your/path/android/sdk